# Can I route packets between PPTP clients?

Tags: pptp, route

I hava one pptp gateway(192.168.1.1), and one pptp linux client(192.168.1.2), and one pptp windows

client(192.168.1.3), When gateway receives response packets of 192.168.1.3 , can i forward these

packets to 192.168.1.2?

Comment: What you're describing is not really routing if they're all on the same subnet.  Can I ask what you're trying to accomplish?  There's (likely) a different/better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: If the IPs have the same 192.168.1.0/24 prefix does not always mean they are in the same VLAN. You can have PPP interfaces with /32 prefixes.

Comment: @gravyface, that's my problem http://serverfault.com/questions/203324/how-to-forward-packets-from-ppp-interface

Comment: gravyface: it is still be routing due to all packets would go over point-to-point channel in despite of what net mask assigned to peers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an option in the PPTP server to allow the clients to inter-communicate. I suggest to use a better/secure VPN solution like OpenVPN, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can't but your router could. :-) Just be sure to enable it doing so: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`